# Request for high quality Titan II turbopump audio

Tags: history, sound, project-gemini, turbopump, titan-rocket

I'm making a historical spaceflight mod and I'm close to starting work on Titan II. Does anybody have high-quality audio clips of the Titan bwoop?

All I have right now are the news broadcasts for Gemini 6 and some others, but those are pretty muddy.

Comment: Potentially helpful from The Vintage Space: [Why did the Gemini Launches Make a Bwooping Sound?](https://youtu.be/WTJDI4bwtOM)  [@AmyShiraTeitel](https://twitter.com/AmyShiraTeitel) does a nice vocal imitation after 01:40 :-)